# Regex to copy all files and folders except one

Tags: regex, gruntjs

My folder structure is:

```
www     
 |--src-files  
 |--scripts  
 |--images  
 |--css
```

Need to copy all files and folders in www except `src-files` using grunt copy. The current src is `['**/*','!**/*.(scss,sass,css)']`
How can I change the regular expression in src to avoid `src-files` folder only from the list to copy?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, by adding `'!**/src-files'` at the end of the array.

Comment: thanks Wiktor. I tried but that is not working

Comment: try `!src-files/*`